# Passing a pre-defined variable from shell script to shell script in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, sh

This is my first time using a shell script.

I have one "Mother" script `mainscript.sh`, in which I define the variable `patientid`.

```
patientid=`basename $folder`
```

Later on in the same script, I wish to execute a separate script `example.sh` while passing the variable `patientid` into it. That script already has the variable labeled as "`$patientid`" in it. Looking at `mainscript.sh` below:

```
./example.sh #I WANT TO PASS THE VARIABLE patientid INTO HERE!
```

I know this is easy-peasy for y'all. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Does `example.sh` only refer to `$patientid` or does it set it somewhere, like in `patientid=somevalue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, what you need is to pass the parameter through the command line arguments, i.e.:

```
./example.sh $patientid
```

in the main script and

```
patientid=$1
```

in the `example.sh` script.

Comment: so, having `patientid=$1` will automatically define it in `example.sh` the way it was defined in `mainscript.sh`? Just by adding `$patientid` after the execution command?

Comment: Right. `./example.sh $patientid` will execute `./example.sh` with `$patientid` as the command line argument. On the other side, the script `example.sh` will be able to access that argument as `$1` (which is a standard name for the first command line argument) and assign it to `patientid` by doing `patientid=$1`. Obviously, this command will overwrite the old content of `patientid` in `example.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling `example.sh`, mark `patientid` for export to the environment of child processes (such as the shell that will run `example.sh`):

```
export patientid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run any shell script (in fact, even binary programs) with a set of variables predefined with

```
 VAR1=value1 VAR2=value2 ... script.sh
```

e.g.

```
 patientid=$patientid mainscript.sh
```

This assumes a Bourne-heritage shell (sh, bash, ash, ksh, zsh, ...)